# How to print all Network Interfaces with PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to print all the network interfaces and disconnected interfaces as well. So far I have the code below:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="interface">
        <?php 
        exec("ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'", $interfaces);

        foreach($interfaces as $int) {
          $select = '';
          if( $int == $conf['interface'] ) {
            $select = "selected";
          }
            echo '<option value="'.$int.'"'.$select.'>'.$int.'</option>';
          }
        ?>
        </select>
```

I am trying to print all network interfaces but one network which is disconnected does not show. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
ip -o link show | grep -vi down | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
```

should work.